# How to display an OpenGL rendered scene within the texture of an OpenGL object?

Tags: opengl

I am assuming that I'll have to render offscreen and then copy that into the texture that I've applied to my main OpenGL scene. Is that the case?

If so, how is that (IIRC it is called compositing) using regular OpenGL function calls?

I am doing this under OS/X but I want it to be portable e.g. to OpenGL/ES.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use an `FBO` (Framebuffer Object) for this. A framebuffer object uses the current OpenGL context, but draws to textures or other types of buffers that are attached to it rather than drawing to the screen. Apple has some pretty good [documentation on getting it working here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_offscreen/opengl_offscreen.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH403-SW2).

Once you've drawn to a texture, you can detach it from the FBO and use it like any other texture, such as applying it to an object you're drawing to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In general, below is how you do it with an FBO. This is not compositing.

```
//Creation of FBO
glGenFramebuffers(NUM_FBO, fboId);
//fbo texture
glGenTextures(NUM_FBO, fboTextureId);
//Regular first texture
glGenTextures(1, &regularTextureId);
//Bind offscreen texture
GL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
GL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTextureId[i]));
GL_CHECK(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, inTextureWidth, inTextureHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL));
GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
GL_CHECK(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId[i]));
GL_CHECK(glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTextureId[i], 0));
if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    goto err;
}
//Bind regular texture
GL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
GL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, regularTextureId));
add_texture(inTextureWidth, inTextureHeight, textureData, inPixelFormat);
GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
//Draw with regular draw calls to FBO
GL_CHECK(_test17(1));
//Now get back display framebuffer and unbind the FBO
GL_CHECK(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0));
GL_CHECK(glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0));
if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    goto err;
}
//bind to texture
GL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
GL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTextureId[i]));
GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
//draw other 3D objects with regular vertex/texure coordinates, use the above texture and then call swapbuffers
draw_regular();
```

A full working version may be found in number of online tutorials, including mine at https://github.com/prabindh/sgxperf/blob/master/sgxperf_test17.